# regular expressions: match x times OR y times

Tags: regex

Lets say I need to match a pattern if it appears 3 or 6 times in a row. The closest I can get is something like \d{3,6} but that doesn't quite do what I need.

'123' should match
'123456' should match
'1234' should not match

Comment: To match `X or Y or Z or ...` times, see the more pragmatic and readable (although not pure regex) solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37351977/6047827

Answer (score 45):

```
^(\d{3}|\d{6})$
```

You have to have some sort of terminator otherwise `\d{3}` will match 1234. That's why I put ^ and $ above. One alternative is to use lookarounds:

```
(?<!\d)(\d{3}|\d{6})(?!\d)
```

to make sure it's not preceded by or followed by a digit (in this case). More in [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: This looks good, thanks. But what if the pattern is much larger than just \d? I guess I could do some string interpolation when building the regular expression but is there a better way to reuse sub-patterns?

Comment: In that case you would want to use the {1,2} format, i.e., ((<baseRegex>){3}){1,2}

Answer (score 17):

How about:

```
(\d\d\d){1,2}
```

although you'll also need guards at either end which depend on your RE engine, something like:

```
[^\d](\d\d\d){1,2}[^\d]
```

or:

```
^(\d\d\d){1,2}$
```

Answer (score 5):

For this case we can get away with this crafty method:

### Clean Implementation

```regex
/(\d{3}){1,2}/
/(?:\d{3}){1,2}/
```

#### How?!

This works because we're looking for multiples of three that are consecutive in this case.

**Note**: There's no reason to capture the group for this case so I add the `?:` non capture group flag to the capture group.

This is similar to `paxdiablo` implementation, but slightly cleaner.

### Matching Hex

I was doing something similar for matching on basic hex colors since they could be 3 or 6 in length. This allowed me to keep my hex color checker's matching DRY'd up ie:

```regex
/^0x(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

First one matches 3, 6 but also 9, 12, 15, .... Second looks right. Here's one more twist:

```
\d{3}\d{3}?
```

Comment: First and second what? If you're referring to someone else's answer, you should say which one it is. These answers don't always appear in the same order.