# Regex to Match the first 6 digits of a phone number

Tags: regex

ok guys I have a list of Phone Numbers like:

```
2017582043
3928530146
2791047392
7684038294
```

and the list goes on an on

what I am trying to do is loop thru the list returning the first 6 digits of each number

May somebody help me figure out that it the correct regex for that?

Comment: What language is this? It would seem basic string splitting is more suitable.

Comment: If you're using PHP, what's wrong with $sixdigits = substr($phone_no,0,6);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the first 6 digits you just have to do `^\d{6}` for each line.  This is for python so your syntax may change based on your language.

Answer (score 1):

If all that you want is to get the first 6 digits, then do not use regex for that, depending on the language, you can extract the first 6 characters easily from a string, using one of the string manipulation functions. Or if the language stores the string as an array of characters, it is even easier. I presume that the first 6 characters are always digits.

Which language are you working with?

Answer (score 1):

`^` = start, `\d` = number, `{6}` = 6 times.

```
/^\d{6}/
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like this /^(\d{6})\d+/ and you can then use $1 as your replacement.

See [regular expressions: match x times OR y times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866538/regular-expressions-match-x-times-or-y-times) which is  a similar but more complex issue.